# TPL DataFlow not executing

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fetchImageFlag = new TransformBlock<string, (string, byte[])>(
            async urlImage => {
                Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {urlImage}");
                using var webClient = new WebClient();
                var data = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(urlImage); 
                return (urlImage, data);
            });

        var saveData = new ActionBlock<(string, byte[])>(data => { 
            (string urlImage, byte[] image) = data;
            Console.WriteLine($"==> UrlImage: {urlImage}");
        });

        fetchImageFlag.LinkTo(saveData); 

        List<string> urlFlags = new List<string>{
            "Italy#/media/File:Flag_of_Italy.svg",
            "Spain#/media/File:Flag_of_Spain.svg",
            "United_States#/media/File:Flag_of_the_United_States.svg"
        };

        foreach (var urlFlag in urlFlags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Calling: {urlFlag}");
            fetchImageFlag.Post($"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{urlFlag}");
        }

    }
}
```

which is taken from this [post](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1483/parallel-workflow-dotnet-tpl-dataflow).

However, when I run it, I only get:

```bash
Calling: Italy#/media/File:Flag_of_Italy.svg
Calling: Spain#/media/File:Flag_of_Spain.svg
Calling: United_States#/media/File:Flag_of_the_United_States.svg
```

I was also expecting to see the `"Downloading {File}"` and `==> UrlImage: {urlImage}` parts.

Comment: Unrelated: using WebClient is discouraged for new development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the [Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2.complete?view=net-5.0) method on `fetchImageFlag` after posting all the messages and wait for [Completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2.completion?view=net-5.0) on the last block `saveData`. Otherwise your application just terminates before any actual job starts or completes.
Also make sure to set `PropagateCompletion=true` on the Link method call.

```
public static void Main()
{
    ....

    fetchImageFlag.LinkTo(saveData, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true});
    ....

    foreach (var urlFlag in urlFlags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling: {urlFlag}");
        fetchImageFlag.Post($"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{urlFlag}");
    }

    fetchImageFlag.Complete();
    saveData.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Also note that the `Console.WriteLine("Downloading {File}", urlImage);` is invalid and should be: `Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {urlImage}");` instead.

Comment: And it should be `await`ed not `.Wait()`ed for.

Comment: Fixed the "Console.WriteLine" in OP